# Power BI - Calculate the number of units produced per SKU, in the timeframe selected by the slicer

Tags: dynamic, datatable, measure

I have a problem in Power BI. I want to calculate the total number of units produced per SKU, in the time frame selected on a slicer. As you can see (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Hph.png), I want to get different results on the quantity of products produced per SKU according to the respective month. However I don't know how to do it without a table to save the results, however a table isn't dynamic. I know that Measure is dynamic, however I don't know how to apply it in this case.

I need the total quantity produced per SKU because then I want to know how many SKUs have been produced more than 2 times, 4 times, etc. I also want to know, the total quantity of products of the SKUs that were produced more than 2 times, 4 times, etc.

Thank you in advance!